# Java graphics, making the window flash in different colors

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics

this is my first post here. I am currently learning about basic GUI and Graphics in java. I'm still pretty new to the language, and it's my first language as well. As I learn java I like to experiment and play with the new tools I acquire from reading. As a result I wanted to make a window where the colors it is filled with will flash, currently, i wanted to stay simple and have it flash from orange to cyan and back. However, right now, all my program does is start white, and fill in with cyan and the text, and then stop changing whatsoever, and I'm not sure why this is.

Please point me in the right direction, thanks!

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.*;

public class ColorFlash extends JFrame{

    private static class Display extends JPanel{ 

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
            super.paintComponent(g);
            for(int h = 200; h > 25; h--){
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
                g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
                g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
                g.drawString("Hello world!", 30, 35);
                g.drawOval(100, 100, 60, 60);
            }
        }
    }

    private static class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener{
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args){
        Display displayPanel = new Display();
        JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
        ButtonHandler listener = new ButtonHandler();
        okButton.addActionListener(listener);

        JPanel content = new JPanel();
        content.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        content.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //subContent.add(displayPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        //content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        content.add(okButton, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        JFrame window = new JFrame("GUI Test");
        window.setContentPane(content);
        window.setSize(500, 500);
        window.setLocation(100,100);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Look up `Swing Timer`. Change the state of your variables in the Timer and call `repaint()` so the paintComponent method can use those changes to help it decide what to draw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) and [Painting in AWT and Swing](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Basically, what's happening is whatever is painted last in your loop is what is actually been painted to the screen

What you need is some kind of timer/trigger that can change the color you want to paint with and repaint the component.

Take a look at [How to use Swing Timers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) for more details

For example...

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestPaint {

    private static class Display extends JPanel {

        private Color[] colors = new Color[]{Color.ORANGE, Color.CYAN};
        private int colorIndex;

        public Display() {
            Timer timer = new Timer(250, new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    setBackground(colors[colorIndex % 2]);
                    colorIndex++;
                }
            });
            timer.start();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(Color.ORANGE);
            g.drawString("Hello world!", 30, 35);
            g.drawOval(100, 100, 60, 60);
        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestPaint();
    }

    public TestPaint() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new Display());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

You might also like to take a look at [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)